# ArcMap 10.2 crashes when running a Model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

We have a feature class "A" with features that are modified by our users on a daily basis. One attribute is the "Date of Modification" that is being written for each edit done on a feature. We have another feature class "B" that contains the same features (with some different attributes) in which we want to "*copy*" all features that have been modified in feature class A and, at the same time, delete the same features in feature class B so that only the new modified ones exist.

We have created a model for this. It starts with the *Select Layer By Attribute* tool to select all features that have `"Date of Modification" = CURRENT_DATE` from feature class "A". Another *Select Layer By Attribute* tool selects the same features from feature class "B" (based on a common field, unique for each feature). Then the *Delete Features* tool is used to delete the selection from feature class "B" and the *Append* tool is used to append the selection from feature class "A" to feature class "B". In between, because we need a specific attribute of the features that is only contained in feature class "B", before we proceed with delete features from "B", we use *Make Feature Layer* to keep this selection and then *Merge* it with the selection coming from feature class "A" and *Dissolve* them on the unique field to keep one feature and the neccesary attributes.

The problem: When we run the model on a local geodatabase with 100 features (for testing) everything works fine. When we run the model on our production feature classes (Oracle SDE) with 500.000 features, the model crashes ArcMap when it reaches the Merge tool:

> "Error:  ArcMap.exe has encountered an error and needs to close. We apologize for the inconvenience" with the option to send an error report to ESRI.

Comment: Sounds like you need to send an error report to ESRI - as the error message suggests

Comment: Is it possible to convert this to a Python script?  Python can be more forgiving than ModelBuilder.